# want to add a hidden input field dynamically in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have 2 buttons and depending on which one is clicked I want to pass that data to the form which is on the same page
so I am trying to add a hidden input field with that value but it does not seem to work

I want to use this to post a form in PHP so any alternate solutions are also welcome.

I have tried this code but no go

```
(function () {

    $(".downloadBrochure").click(function () {
        if (this.id == "basicBrochure") {
            $("<input type='text' class='hidden' name='package' id='packagetype' value='Basic'>").appendTo("#brochure");
            // $('#packagetype').html("Basic");
        }
        else {

            // $('#packagetype').html("Plus");
        }
        $(".modal-content").show();
    });

})();
```

My HTML form is

```
<div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                {!! Form::open(array('url' => '/saveRequestInfo', 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => 'brochure')) !!}
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="txt_name" id="txt_name" class="form-control"
                               required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Phone" name="txt_phone" id="txt_phone" class="form-control"
                               required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="txt_email" id="txt_email" class="form-control"
                               required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <input type="text" class="hidden" name="url" id="url"
                       value="<?= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ? $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : ""; ?>">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 text-center">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary callback" name="btn_call">
                            Download Brochure
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
        </div>
```

Please assist

Comment: you should use type="hidden" instead of type="text"

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: @Graveyard This is not the hidden input , I want to add a new hidden input which will have the package type which I will have to retirneve from the button clicked..

Comment: @Lain I want to add a new input field which will have a value which will depend on the button clicked

Answer (score 1):

You should not use *IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)* because it runs it before DOM gets ready, Instead you change it to `document.ready` block:

```
jQuery(function ($) { // <-----use the doc ready block this way

    $(".downloadBrochure").click(function () {
        if (this.id == "basicBrochure") {
            $("<input type='hidden' name='package' id='packagetype' value='Basic'>").appendTo("#brochure");
            // $('#packagetype').html("Basic");
        }
        else {

            // $('#packagetype').html("Plus");
        }
        $(".modal-content").show();
    });

}); // <-------remove it here
```

And as in comment suggestions is that if you require to have a hidden input element then you should use `type="hidden"` which can give you the input element and it is not visible to the user.

Comment: @DhavalChheda How you are putting it there. As i don't see any button with the class name `downloadBrochure` and `id` named `basicBrochure`.

Comment: That button is the button that will be clicked and the #brochure is the id of the form

Comment: @DhavalChheda Okay! what i meant was does the button you posted is the actual button which is getting clicked. if yes then the event is not bound to it because it doesn't have the class name of `downloadBrochure`.

Comment: the click event is bound to .downloadBrochure

Comment: `<button class="btn btn-primary callback" name="btn_call">
                            Download Brochure
                        </button>` Are you talking about this button?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129525/discussion-between-dhaval-chheda-and-jai).